# Выход из цикла while Python

Tags: python, файлы, while

Как сделать так чтоб слово 'quit' не входила в общий список гостей.

```py
guestt = True
    while guestt:
        guestt = input("Pleas write your name: ")
        guest_list.write(f"Hello j{guestt} nice to meet you\n")
        if guestt == "quit":
            break
```

Comment: Переставить write ниже проверки if ... break

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я возможно не так вас понял. Но может быть вы хотели что-то такое:

```py
guestt = True

while guestt:
    guestt = input("Pleas write your name: ")
    
    if guestt == "quit": # Условие надо поставить до добавления в список
        break
    
    guest_list.write(f"Hello j{guestt} nice to meet you\n")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Сначала проверь что `guest` равно на "quit" иначе оно записывается на массив а потом проверяется

```py
signup = True
    while signup:
        guest = input("Pleas write your name: ")
        if guest == "quit":
            break
        guest_list.write(f"Hello j{guest} nice to meet you\n")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое